# ajax call does not work second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a form to show the result of a database depend on 2 entries. Here Automarke (in english brand) and Modell (model), see [2 entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boBEo.png)

The box Modell changes just in time, depend on Automarke. Here I use:

```
            $(MainInput).on('change' , Marke, function() {
            // $( Marke ).change(function() {
                //remove all options
                $( Modell).find('option').remove();             
                var brand = $( Marke ).find('option:selected').text();
                $.ajax({
                        url: '/hk/phpscript/getModel.php',
                        //url: 'schreibeMail.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        //data: { var_PHP_data: var_data },
                        data: { brand: brand },
                        success: function(data) {
                            // do something;
                            test = data;
                            var arr = JSON.parse(test);
                            var help = "";
                            for(i = 0; i <= arr.length - 1; i++){
                            $(Modell).append("<option>" + arr[i].Modell + "</option>");
                            $(Modell).selectpicker('refresh');
                            }
                        }
                });
            });
```

Everything works. The connection occurs with ajax and php, see the code below

```
            //click search
            $(search).on('click' , searchCar, function() {
            // $(searchCar).click(function() {

                if( $(Marke).val() == "" || $(Modell).val() == "")
                {   
                    alert("Bitte wählen Sie eine Automarke und ein Modell aus!");
                    return;
                }
                whereCondition = setSearchQuery();
                // alert(whereCondition);
                //alert(value);
                alert(whereCondition);
                //function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/hk/phpscript/getCar.php',
                    //url: 'schreibeMail.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    //data: { var_PHP_data: var_data },
                    data: { whereCondition: whereCondition },
                    success: function(data) {
                    alert(whereCondition);
                    ... do anything with data
                    }
```

I get the results from the database. After that, 2 problems occurs.

1) A change of the Automarke parameter does not change the Modell inputs, as it was possible before
2) A second search is not possible, the form does not react. Can be identify - no alert message appears.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you.

Reg

Samir

EDIT:

Any javascript function does not work, after i clicked the button. It doesnt  react if i change the value of "Automarke". Normally the "Modell" dropdown menu gets new values, if "Automarke changes the value.

Comment: `as it was possible before` ... before what? Also, alerts are not used by serious programmers for debugging code - use `console.log` ... and check the console for errors as well

Comment: I take it `MainInput`, `Marke` and `Modell` are variables, not supposed to be string literals, right?

Comment: Here another indicator. The first click of the search button works. But if i click it once more, any fields and drop down menus have the value 'undefined'...

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Like This:

```js
$(document).on('change','selector',function(){
//your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i found my mistake. I used `$(Marke).val()` instead of `$('#Marke')`.

After using `$(Marke).val()`, the value was `undefined` and that causes the error, if i click the button again.